# I am not able to push my files using git push

Tags: git, github

I am really having a tough time pushing my files using the git push command. I normally do it easily but all of a sudden it began requesting my username and password and when i entered the correct credentials, it says they are not correct.

I don't know if there is a manual method to use to fix this.

Comment: I don't think this is enough for us to help you in resolving your issue. But you can try public key authentication instead.

Comment: Do you have write access to the repository? Did you enable 2FA?

Comment: I already disabled 2FA after reading some article which explained that, the 2FA might be the cause of the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get accross with this. I think thats the new way github does some kind of it's authentication.

After entering either of my username/email and password. The first time, it gives an error that reads `logon authentication failed, please try again` and then the second time i input my correct credentials, it throws the same error but then pushes the update. It's kinda strange.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use git command line? There are alot easier options if you go the route of vscode or something like github desktop to do all the dirty work of mastering the command line interface.

There are alot of tutorials however in google if you insist to go through the CLI interface of how to reset and THEN change username and password in the vim mode of git command line interface.

But trying to remember those commands for everytime somethings goes south, is a time waster, it's better to use a proper interface that is provided by as mentioned from vscode, github desktop etc...

That's just my two cents.